# Forward defining class in namespace?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, compiler-bug

The following snippet fails to compile with Visual Studio 2010, but GCC likes it:

```
namespace Test { 
    class Baz;
    // Adding class Bar; here and removing the class below makes it work
    // with VC++, but it should work like this, shouldn't it?
    void Foo (Baz& b, class Bar& c);
}

namespace Test { 
    class Bar
    {
        // Making this method non-template works
        template <typename T>
        static void Lalala ()
        {
        }
    };
}

int main ()
{
}
```

Am I doing something stupid here or is this a valid compiler bug? The error I get is:
`error C2888: 'void Bar::Foo(void)' : symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'Test'`

It compiles with GCC 4.5.1: http://ideone.com/7sImY

[Edit] Just to be clear, I want to know if this is valid C++ or not (and if so, why not) -- workarounds to get it compiled are nice but not part of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code is well-formed.  But proving that for certain would require making sure there's nothing in the Standard that contradicts the usage.

Some relevant quotes from the C++11 Standard:

3.3.2 p6:

> The point of declaration of a class first declared in an *elaborated-type-specifier* is as follows:

- for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form *class-key identifier*

  - if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq* or *parameter-declaration-clause* of a
    function defined in namespace scope, the *identifier* is declared as a *class-name* in the namespace that
    contains the declaration; otherwise, except as a friend declaration, the *identifier* is declared in the
    smallest non-class, non-function-prototype scope that contains the declaration.

3.4.4 p2:

> If the *elaborated-type-specifier* has no *nested-name-specifier*, and unless the elaborated-type-specifier appears in a declaration with the following form:
>   *class-key attribute-specifier-seq opt identifier* `;`
>   the *identifier* is looked up according to 3.4.1 but ignoring any non-type names that have been declared. ... If the *elaborated-type-specifier* is introduced by
>   the *class-key* and this lookup does not find a previously declared *type-name*, or if the *elaborated-type-specifier*
>   appears in a declaration with the form:
>   *class-key attribute-specifier-seq opt identifier* `;`
>   the *elaborated-type-specifier* is a *declaration* that introduces the *class-name* as described in 3.3.2.

7.1.6 has some syntax definitions establishing that an *elaborated-type-specifier* can syntactically be a *type-specifier*.  7.1 establishes that a *type-specifier* can syntactically be a *decl-specifier*, which is the syntactical unit used as the type in a function *parameter-declaration* (8.3.5).

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Well, I tried it in [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/Ka2sUJkC) too and it compiles, but I'm not sure it should (not THAT proficient in C++ compiler functionality)!</strike>

**Workaround:** forward declare `Bar` as well or you have to define `Bar` before you make `Foo`. In other words, this compiles in MSVC:

```
namespace Test 
{ 
    class Baz;
    class Bar;// also forward-declare Bar
    void Foo (Baz& b, class Bar& c);
}

namespace Test 
{ 
    class Bar
    {
        template <typename T>
        static void Foo ()
        {
        }
    };
}

int main(void)
{

    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**
I think that this might already be a bug reported to Microsoft... this looks pretty close: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/99218/invalid-error-c2888-when-a-class-is-defined-after-it-is-declared

The workaround cited by Microsoft:

```
A stand-alone forward declaration consists of an elaborated type specifier followed by a semicolon.

insert the declaration

class C2888;

before the declaration of foo(C2888o, C2888).
```

Comment: The `class Bar` *should* be the forward declaration, though. I think that's the entire point of the question.

Comment: Yeah, Kerrek is right. I know that it works if I forward declare even earlier, but this should work as well. It would work if Bar didn't have a template method for instance ...

Comment: Anteru, it looks like it's a bug in MSVC and Microsoft is not going to fix it: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/99218/invalid-error-c2888-when-a-class-is-defined-after-it-is-declared

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is a compiler bug.

Changing the order of parameters will change the compilation result.

```
namespace Test { 
void Foo (class Bar& b, class Baz& c) - will compile.
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The `class Bar` construct is erroneous. Are you, by any chance, a C programmer who didn't use `typedef struct { /* members */ } Foo`?

Anywho, you need to define both Bar and Baz inside test:

```
namespace Test {
    class Bar;
    class Baz;
};
```

And remove `class`, `struct`, `union`, and `enum` keywords when declaring function parameters.

With that modification, it compiles cleanly in g++4.6.

Comment: OP said in the Question GCC compiles it, MSVC doesn't.

Comment: Using `class Bar` as a type is sometimes permitted.  It's just usually a good idea to avoid that, since the "sometimes" is complicated.

Comment: It compiles with GCC _as it is now_ (GCC 4.5.1 and GCC4.6.1), so this is not helpful.

Comment: @aschepler Cite the section of ISO 14882 where this construct is defined. It looks like fwd-declarations in parameters should be uncompilable.

Comment: Anywho, in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27zksbks.aspx it looks like MSVC is picky with scope and function-parameter scope is a no-no - it must be in namespace (and by extension, class) scope.

Comment: Where do you see that on the page?

Comment: "A symbol belonging to namespace A must be defined in a namespace that encloses A", implying namespace-scope definitions only.